# ¿como concatenar mas de un array?

Tags: php, mysql

hola como podría concatenar mas de un array por ejemplo tengo este código me almacena un array de nombres pero necesito que me almacene la variable cantidad y estado

código corregido pero aun no inserta nada en la base de datos

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());

$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];
$estado=$_POST['estado'];

//Creamos un arreglo que tendra los arrglos que conforman los campos nombre, cantidad y estado
$arreglo_de_valores = [];
for($posicion = 0; $posicion <= count($_POST['nombre'])); $posicion++{

    //Obtenemos el valor de la varibale dentro del array POST
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'][$posicion];
    $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'][$posicion];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'][$posicion];

    //Los valores los guardamos como un arreglo
    $arreglo_de_valores[] = array(
        $nombre, //Posicion 0
        $cantidad, //Posicion 1
        $estado //Posicion 2
    );
}
foreach($arreglo_de_valores as $valores){
$sql="INSERT INTO checklist_accesorios (nombre,cantidad,estado) VALUES ($valores[0], $valores[1], $valores[2])";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Problemas al insertar".mysqli_error());

   }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

así tengo mis input con el name[] quisas el error sea en el estado que son varios y por lo tanto no me deja almacenar nada en la base de datos

```
<label>Emblemas</label>
<input type="text" name="nombre[]" id="emblemas" value="Emblemas">
<label>Cantidad</label>
<input type="text" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad">
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="estado[]" value="bueno">Bueno
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="estado[]" value="malo">Malo
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="estado[]" value="no_aplica">NA
</label>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="nombre[]" id="unidades" value="Unidades">unidades
<input type="text" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad">cantidad
<input type="radio" name="estado[]" value="bueno">bueno
<input type="radio" name="estado[]" value="malo">malo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());

$nombres = $_POST['nombre'];
$cantidades = $_POST['cantidad'];
$estados = $_POST['estado'];

for($i=0; $i < count($nombres); $i++){ 
  $nombre= $nombres[$i];
  $cantidad= $cantidades[$i];
  $estado= $estados[$i];

  $sql="INSERT INTO checklist_accesorios (nombre, cantidad, estado) VALUES ('$nombre', '$cantidad', '$estado')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Problemas al insertar".mysqli_error());
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Considera añadir una explicación a tu respuesta

Comment: me funciono en parte ya se agregan los nombres y las cantidades pero como manejo los radiobuttons son los que llevan el array name=estado[] arriba edite mi pregunta y aparece como tengo mis inputs

Comment: si pongo esto a mis radiobuttons name=estado[] de todos los que tengo solo me deja elegir uno, cuando deben de estar separados en la primera opción solo me debe permitir elegir una opción de las tres bueno ,malo, na, y en la otra opción bueno o malo

Comment: es porque estas usando [input type="radio"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) y para lo que describes deberías usar [input type="checkbox"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

Comment: cierto ya lo corregí y ya funciona muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

El siguiente código lo he probado en mi maquina y funciona a la perfección, solo que encontré un error con los radiobutton que a continuación expongo:

- La estructura de los radiobuttons es de agrupación por lo que al
  colocarlos todos con el mismo nombre mas corchetes hacia que todos
  los radiobuttons pertenecieran al mismo grupo en todo el formulario.

Para solucionar este problema lo que hago es que, por cada fila del formulario al nombre del radiobutton le agrego al final `_n` donde `n` es un numero incremental iniciando en 0. De esta forma ya puede obtener su valor en el ciclo `for`

- Al ejecutar el código teniendo un error, en pantalla se mostraba el siguiente mensaje `Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in`

Esto se  soluciona pasando le como parámetro a la función la variable que guarda la conexión. Para este caso es `$con`

Por otro lado, note que tenia código de mas que bien puede ser suprimido, dejo el código funcional.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());

    for($posicion = 0; $posicion < count($_POST['nombre']); $posicion++){

        //Obtenemos el valor de la varibale dentro del array POST
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'][$posicion];
        $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'][$posicion];
        $estado = $_POST['estado_'.$posicion];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO checklist_accesorios(nombre, cantidad, estado) VALUES('$nombre', '$cantidad', '$estado')";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("Problemas al insertar".mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>

<form action="pruebafoorm.php" method="POST">
    <label>Emblemas</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre[]" id="emblemas" value="Emblemas">
    <label>Cantidad</label>
    <input type="text" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="estado_0" value="bueno">Bueno
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="estado_0" value="malo">Malo
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="estado_0" value="no_aplica">NA
    </label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Emblemas</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre[]" id="emblemas" value="Emblemas">
    <label>Cantidad</label>
    <input type="text" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="estado_1" value="bueno">Bueno
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="estado_1" value="malo">Malo
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="estado_1" value="no_aplica">NA
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: si asi tengo mi formulario name="nombre[]", name="cantidad[]" y name="estado []" pusiste mi mismo código en tu ejemplo no ?

Comment: Nada por lo que pedir perdon.. capaz fue un error involuntario y por eso lo avisaba ;)

Comment: Ya esta la respuesta completa @JasielTorres. Una disculpa di un Enter y la respuesta fue publicada aun sin terminarla.

Comment: Una cosa.. por como estructuraste la respuesta, no queda claro que el $sql que tiene que usar es el que escribiste despues. Pero la respuesta esta bien..

Comment: Tienes razón @gbianchi y considerando las necesidades de quien pregunta es mejor que solo deje el que permite hacer la respuesta mas clara.

Comment: corrige mi código como me lo indicaste pero ahora ya no guarda nada antes guardaba solo la variable nombre , edite mi pregunta para que vean como tengo el código y los inputs

Comment: Te aparece algún error @JasielTorres?

Comment: no aparece error solo no inserta los datos